# Easiest way to consume text returned from a REST service

Tags: rest, iframe, xmlhttprequest, jsonp, restful-url

I need to display on my Web page a simple text string returned from a REST service. I am currently using an XMLHttpRequest:

```
<div id="returnedText"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    document.getElementById("returnedText").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
}
};
xhr.open("GET",url,true);
xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

Isn't there a lighter way? I considered using a script tag but the Web service in question doesn't support JSONP. I also did a naive attempt with an iframe (putting the REST url as src) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did another attempt with iframes and actually this works fine:

```
<iframe src="url"></iframe>
```

Where url is the REST service call.

I must have done something wrong the first time (maybe an authentication issue).

Comment: What type of calls have you tried? Have you tried to do a POST call though the src? If so does that work?

Comment: @CroconosterShaneVanWyk I haven't tried, and I don't think you can do a POST call that way (unless maybe you tweak your browser). My question is actually specific to GET requests.

Comment: I have solved my POST by doing a submit on the form which contains the url. Do that on page load, form method="post". For future references. Then i just use the target="<The IFrame>" Quite handy, now trying to display the the frame correctly size wise is a whole different story

Answer (score 1):

Well the iframe route is clunky since you'd be loading the REST response into it and then reaching into it via JS to get the response. What's more, it would cause a visible load in the browser's address bar area. AJAX came along to do away with the iframe hack :)

JSON-P requires about as much setup as AJAX and if your server doesn't support the callback, that's a none starter.

AJAX needn't be thought heavy. Kick it into its own utility function or, even better, use a library, which makes requests like these do'able in one line. jQuery example:

```
$.get('some/path').done(function(response) { /* do something */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. My issue with iframes is that the response doesn't even load (or else I'd be very happy as I just need to display the text, I don't even need to reach into it). As for jQuery, let's keep in mind that it's one line of visible code, but hundreds of lines behind the scene...